# Change reference to function in run-time in Python

Tags: python, bytecode, introspection

I need to change a call to a function inside another function during run-time.

Consider the following code:

```
def now():
    print "Hello World!"

class Sim:
    def __init__(self, arg, msg):
        self.msg = msg
        self.func = arg
        self.patch(self.func)

    def now(self):
        print self.msg

    def run(self):
        self.func()

    def patch(self, func):
        # Any references to the global now() in func
        # are replaced with the self.now() method.

def myfunc():
    now()
```

Then ...

```
>>> a = Sim(myfunc, "Hello Locals #1")
>>> b = Sim(myfunc, "Hello Locals #2")
>>> b.run()
Hello Locals #2
>>> a.run()
Hello Locals #1
```

One user has written code, `myfunc()`, that makes a call to a globally defined function `now()` and I cannot edit it. But I want it to call the method of the `Sim` instance instead. So I would need to "patch" the `myfunc()` function in run-time.

How could I go about this?

One possible solution is to edit the bytecode as done here:
http://web.archive.org/web/20140306210310/http://www.jonathon-vogel.com/posts/patching_function_bytecode_with_python but I'm wondering if there is an easier way.

Comment: In your actual use-case, are `now` and `myfunc` defined in the same module as each other? Do you care if other usages of `now` are affected? If they are in different modules, how does `myfunc` access the `now` function? The required approach might be a bit different if it does `from somemodule import now ... now()` vs `import somemodule ... somemodule.now()`.

Comment: Yes, it does matter. I updated the example to account for this. The end user would import the global ``now`` and ``Sim`` from a library in their code. I could modify the global ``now``, but I cannot afford a costly lookup inside the global ``now`` to locate a local version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is trickier than it might seem. To do it you need to:

- Create a `dict` subclass with a `__missing__` method to hold your new value of `now`. The `__missing__` method then grabs any items not in the dictionary from the usual `globals()` dict.
- Create a new function object from the existing `myfunc()` function, keeping its code object but using the new dictionary you created for globals.
- Assign the new function back into globals using its function name.

Here's how:

```
def now():
    print "Hello World!"

class NowGlobals(dict):
    def __init__(self, now, globals):
        self["now"] = now
        self.globals = globals
    def __missing__(self, key):
        return self.globals[key]

class Sim(object):
    def __init__(self, func):
        func = self.patch(func)
        self.func = func
    def now(self):
        print "Hello locals!"
    def patch(self, func):
        funcname   = func.__name__
        nowglobals = NowGlobals(self.now, func.func_globals)
        func = type(func)(func.func_code, nowglobals)
        globals()[funcname] = func
        return func

def myfunc():
    now()

sim = Sim(myfunc)
myfunc()
```

There is really no need to have it in a class, but I've kept it that way since that's the way you wrote it originally.

If `myfunc` is in another module, you'll need to rewrite `Sim.patch()` to patch back into that namespace, e.g. `module.myfunc = sim.patch(module.myfunc)`

Comment: Will this work on 2 different instances of ``Sim()`` as in the updated code? It looks like it is modifying the original ``myfunc`` and will modify the previous patching. Perhaps deep copying ``myfunc`` first and then patching could do the trick?

Comment: Should work with multiple instances. Obviously only one version of `myfunc` can be in the globals at one time, but if you call it through the `Sim` instance (either making `Sim` callable by adding a `__call__` method, or just by calling `sim.func()`), each uses its own version of `myfunc`. You could also defer the patching until you call the instance.

Comment: This worked great. I would just point out that ``globals()[funcname] = name`` will change the original ``myfunc``, therefore it should be optional depending on the required outcome. I personally just commented it out and now does what I wanted.

Answer (score 1):

This answer is intended for amusement only.  Please don't ever do this.

It can be done by replacing `myfunc` with a wrapper function which makes a copy of the global variable dictionary, replaces the offending `'now'` value, makes a new function with the code object of the original `myfunc` and the new global dictionary, and then calls that new function instead of the original `myfunc`.  Like this:

```
import types
def now():
    print("Hello World!")

class Sim:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.func = arg
        self.patch(self.func)
        self.func()

    def now(self):
        print("Hello Locals!")

    def patch(self, func):

        def wrapper(*args, **kw):
            globalcopy = globals().copy()
            globalcopy['now'] = self.now
            newfunc = types.FunctionType(func.__code__, globalcopy, func.__name__)
            return newfunc(*args, **kw)
        globals()[func.__name__] = wrapper

def myfunc():
    now()

def otherfunc():
    now()
```

Then:

```
>>> myfunc()
Hello World!
>>> otherfunc()
Hello World!
>>> Sim(myfunc)
Hello World!
<__main__.Sim instance at 0x0000000002AD96C8>
>>> myfunc()
Hello Locals!
>>> otherfunc()
Hello World!
```

There are lots of reasons not to do this.  It won't work if the `now` function that `myfunc` accesses is not in the same module as `Sim`.  It might break other things.  Also, having a plain class instantiation like `Sim(myfunc)` change global state in this way is really evil.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `mock` package, which already takes care of much of the hard work in patching a function call. It's a third-party install in Python 2 (and early versions of 3?), but part of the Python 3 standard library as `unittest.mock`. It's mainly intended for testing, but you could try using it here.

```
import mock

def now():
    print "Hello World!"

class Sim:
    # Your code from above here

def myfunc():
    now()

myfunc()   # Outputs Hello World!

s = Sim(myfunc, "Hello Locals #1")
mock.patch('__main__.now', wraps=s.now).start()

myfunc()   # Now outputs Hello Locals #1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not very elegant, but you can wrap your func with another function that modifies the global environment only while func is running.

```
def now():
    print "Hello World!"

class Sim:
    def __init__(self, arg, msg):
        self.msg = msg
    self.func = arg
    self.patch(self.func)

  def now(self):
    print self.msg

  def run(self):
    self.func()

  def patch(self, func):
    # Any references to the global now() in func
    # are replaced with the self.now() method.

    def newfunc():
        global now
        tmp = now
        now = self.now
        func()
        now = tmp

    self.func = newfunc


def myfunc():
    now()
```

Answer (score -1):

Functions have a `func_globals` attribute. In this case you implement `patch` like so:

```
def now():
    print "Hello World!"


class Sim:
    def __init__(self, arg):
        self.func = arg
        self.patch(self.func)
        self.func()

    def now(self):
        print "Hello Locals!"

    def patch(self, func):
        # Any references to the global now() in func
        # are replaced with the self.now() method.
        func.func_globals['now'] = self.now


def myfunc():
    now()


Sim(myfunc)
```

Which prints:

```
Hello World!
Hello Locals!
```

Comment: This will cause *all* calls to `now` to be replaced, not just calls to `now` from within `myfunc`.

Comment: Oops. Missed that. Editing my answer.

Comment: This mixes up the function you want to patch and the function you want the other function to use. Also, it still replaces calls to `now` from other functions in the module.

Comment: Yep, you're right. Being too hasty. The current edit should solve OP's problem.

Comment: Your edit does not solve the problem.  `myfunc.func_globals` is a reference to the global environment, not a copy of it.  Modifying `myfunc.func_globals` has the same effect as modifying the result of `globals()` directly.

Comment: You're right. I'll leave this for posterity until its solved. I'm not sure how to do this.