# Python equivalent of lua's loadfile

Tags: python, function, lua

In lua there is a function called `loadfile`, this function allows the program to parse a .lua file into the current project. All the functions and variables work as if they were written in the same file.

This is useful for loading plugins. I am trying to port a telegram bot over to python but cannot find a function that allows me to load a .py file and have the functions be in the context of the file.

I have tried python's `execfile` and importing the file but that doesn't allow for the functions of the loaded file to be in scope of the initial file.

(i.e. fileA.py loads fileB.py. fileA has function "doThis". fileB can't access "doThis" using execfile)

How can I achieve the same thing in python as loadfile for lua?

I am using python 2

Comment: at the top of fileB: `from fileA import doThis` doesnt work for you? or am i misunderstanding?

Comment: @TehTris It doesn't work for me as the function needs to be able to read the variables on the fileA as if they were in the same file. Also it is a bit tedious needing to do this for everytime I add a plugin.

Comment: are you using python 2 or 3?

Answer (score 0):

You generally shouldn't do this, since wildcard imports can make code harder to debug, but:

```
from other_module import *
```

This imports everything defined in `other_module` into the current module's global namespace. It's not exactly the same, but it's as close as you'll get.

```
execfile("other_module.py", globals())
```

is very similar, except it won't cache the module in `sys.modules`.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I need to be able to get a variable from the files, but each file has the variable named the name. (plugin) My current code allows me to get the variable, but still not global. `values = {}; execfile(file, values); plugin = values['plugin']`

I may be able to make a workaround using your answer though.

Comment: What you want to do in that case is probably the `execfile` thing with an empty dictionary, `{}`. Then fish the same-named object out of the dictionary and put it in one of your own (under the name of the plugin).

Comment: Would this work if it was an array with a function in it, and I made a new function in fileA that was equal to the one in fileB, would this allow the function to use the functions and variables in fileA as if it were written in the file?

Comment: It's possible by constructing a new function object. I outlined how to do that as part of [this recent answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30061421/change-reference-to-function-in-run-time-in-python/30061978#30061978). Basically you need to extract the code object from the function from fileB and make a new function that uses fileA's globals.

Comment: thank you, I will look at this when I get the chance

Comment: I tried to make a function out of the code you had provided in that answer that would create an exact duplicate function of a function with combined globals of the function and the `globals()` but it did not work. I'm sorry if I'm sounding like I just want everything handed to me. I am really trying to get this to work.